# How to send a message to a user?

Tags: discussion

A user, I think it was [DrakaSAN](https://superuser.com/users/242441/drakasan) gave me an answer to [one of my questions](https://superuser.com/q/719331/162573) but as we were commenting I asked for more info and he then deleted the answer. After trying to test what he said (that VLC plays DVD with external subs) I found that it works, only that the Video Output had to be changed from Default to OpenGL (in Windows), an info that he also needed. How can I inform the guy on that, and that he was in fact right and give him the credit?

I do not mean sending a private message, just a public info to come back to my question and answer back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't message a user. You can only comment on their posts and they will get a notification on the site about it.

If they hang out on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/root-access), you might be able to catch them there.